# C recursive typedef struct

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENT 100

typedef struct TreeNode{
    int weight;
    TreeNode *left_child;
    TreeNode *right_child;
} TreeNode;

typedef struct element{
    TreeNode *ptree;
    int key;
} element;

typedef struct HeapType{
    element heap[MAX_ELEMENT];
    int heap_size;
} HeapType;
```

and I get the errors:

```
error: unknown type name ‘TreeNode’
     TreeNode *left_child;
error: unknown type name ‘TreeNode’
     TreeNode *right_child;
```

I can't understand why...can you explain?

Comment: It should work fine if you change the declaration to `struct TreeNode *left_child;`.  You can also add a preceding declaration: `typedef struct TreeNode`; followed by `struct TreeNode { TreeNode *left_child; ... }`

Comment: The bottom line is the `typedef` for `TreeNode` is not complete when you use `TreeNode *left_child;`, etc.. You either include `struct` before `TreeNode *left_child;` or create a `typedef` using a *forward reference* for `struct TreeNode`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your code:

```
typedef struct TreeNode{
    int weight;
    TreeNode *left_child;
    TreeNode *right_child;
} TreeNode;
```

the name `TreeNode` is not known until the line `} TreeNode;` is parsed.  When processing the line `TreeNode *left_child;`, the compiler knows that there is a type `struct TreeNode`, but it doesn't know anything about a type `TreeNode`.

You can also use:

```
typedef struct TreeNode Treenode;

struct TreeNode
{
    int weight;
    TreeNode *left_child;
    TreeNode *right_child;
};
```

The first line says "there is a a structure type `struct TreeNode`, and `TreeNode` is an alias for that type".  The remaining lines of code define what it means to be a `struct TreeNode`.

Alternatively, as the other answers point out, you can use:

```
typedef struct TreeNode
{
    int weight;
    struct TreeNode *left_child;
    struct TreeNode *right_child;
} TreeNode;
```

The compiler knows enough about the type `struct TreeNode` to be able to handle pointers to the type as it reads the definition. Note C11 [§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ¶3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p3):

> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), …

Comment: Both robthebloke and Yoni Melki explained *WHY*the problem is occurring.  Thank you for adding *BOTH* of the two possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write `struct TreeNode*`
because the compiler still doesn’t know what is TreeNode (without the struct)

Answer (score 2):

The typedef doesn't kick in until after the struct definition, so you still need to use the struct keyword for the pointer decls.

```cpp
typedef struct TreeNode{
    int weight;
    struct TreeNode *left_child;
    struct TreeNode *right_child;
} TreeNode;
```